# How to show hidden div section by clicking button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

```
css file
    .middle-section2{
    display: none;
        }
   .middle-section2-area{
    position: absolute;
    left: 250px;
    top: 1600px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    border: 2px hidden;
    padding: 10px;
      }

  .middle-section2-name{
    position: absolute;
    left: 650px;
    top: 1500px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    border: 2px hidden;
    padding: 10px;
      }

  .middle-section2-edit{
    position: absolute;
    left:850px;
    top:1485px;
      }

  .middle-section2-edit img{
    width: 20px;
    margin: 5px;

      }
```

Js file

```
  $(function() {
        $("#middle-section2").hide();
        $("#btn").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#middle-section2").toggle();
        });
    });
```

Html file

```
div class="middle-section2">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="middle-section2-name">
      </div>

      <div class="middle-section2-edit">
        <%= image_tag 'settings-logo.png'%>
      </div>

      <div class="middle-section2-area" >
        <p>carosel</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

<div class="button-field">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="container fluid">
    <button class="button"  id="btn">+</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Im new to rails and , i want to show hiddene div section by clicking button. I tried it with this code. but still it doesn't work . I know some small problem having their. but still couldn't find it. No errors shown by console. but it not work pls help me to make it work

Comment: .middle-section2 is a class and you are referring to an id #middle-section2?

Comment: .middle-section2 work fine. you gave the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing `#middle-section2` to `.middle-section2`

```js
      $(function() {
        $(".middle-section2").hide();
        $("#middle-section2").hide();
        $("#btn").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".middle-section2").toggle();
        });
    });
```

```css
.middle-section2{

width:120px;
height:150px;
display:inline-block;
background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="middle-section2"></div>

<button id="btn">toggle</button>
```